# Two instances are created when launchMode is singleTask and called with different intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have created a sample custom launcher to check the behavior of launchMode and intents. Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml contents:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

After installing the app when it is launched from app drawer, MainActivity starts with the intent - action as MAIN and category as LAUNCHER. Here it creates one instance. After that in Settings, if it is selected as the default launcher, MainActivity starts with the intent - action as MAIN and category as HOME. Here it creates another instance.

But if it is done in the reverse order, that is first from Settings and then from app drawer, it creates only instance.

So, why two instances are created?

Comment: Remove `android:taskAffinity=""` and see if that helps. Otherwise you may have found an Android bug.

Comment: I tried removing that. Still the behavior is same.

Comment: How do you install the app and launch it for the first time?

Comment: App is installed either from android studio or after copying the apk to the device. If it is installed after copying the apk, I launch the app from app drawer.